# How do I get the path of a package installed with PIP, and chang that path?

Tags: python-2.7, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, virtualenv

I installed virtualenv with PIP.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Everything appeared to go smoothly. When I enter

```
$ pip freeze
```

it lists

```
virtualenv==1.10.1
```

I can import it with python just fine

```
$python
...
>>> import virtualenv
>>>
```

Yet when I try to create a virtual env:

```
$virtualenv test
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

I assume this is because of my Path, but I am not sure how to find the path or change it. How do I fix this?

If I do

```
$sudo find /- virtualenv 
/usr/local/share/python/virtualenv
```

When I do

```
brew info python
```

I get

> They will install into the site-package directory
>     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Which is not where virtualenv is. This seems to happen with everything I've loaded with PIP lately. Is there a universal fix to get the directory PIP installs to line up with the directory Python thinks its installing?

Comment: could you dump your path `$echo $PATH`?

Comment: '$ echo $PATH virtualenv'

  returns  

'/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin virtualenv'

Comment: If I do '$sudo find /- virtualenv /usr/local/share/python/virtualenv'

Comment: So you'll need to add that to your path `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/python/virtualenv`